# Load Javascrpit into HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm getting errors that SEEM to be coming from the files the professor wrote, not my own code. I followed the instructions seemingly correctly and, mostly, some of his files are giving CORS errors, even though they SHOULD be using the correct HTTP GET request protocol, which gets around CORS, so I don't understand what the problem is.

So basically, the homework is (and I'll try to be more descriptive than last time), there's a website for a Chinese restaurant that we're updating with Javascript to load HTML dynamically instead of statically like we did previously, and it's pretty involved and complicated but the jist of it is there are menu categories, and I'm supposed to load a random one. Most of the accessory functions have been written for me already, I just have to tweak a few lines following instructions. The result is it should load a random menu category on the homepage. It accesses an external JSON file with menu category data organized in a specific manner using HTTP GET request in a separate ajaxutils.js javascript file. The homework itself is in a file titled script.js. I'll type out the instructions below so you can check if I'm doing it correctly.

```
// TODO: STEP 0: Look over the code from
// *** start ***
// to
// *** finish ***
// below.
// We changed this code to retrieve all categories from the server instead of
// simply requesting home HTML snippet. We now also have another function
// called buildAndShowHomeHTML that will receive all the categories from the server
// and process them: choose random category, retrieve home HTML snippet, insert that
// random category into the home HTML snippet, and then insert that snippet into our
// main page (index.html).
//
// TODO: STEP 1: Substitute [...] below with the *value* of the function buildAndShowHomeHTML,
// so it can be called when server responds with the categories data.

// *** start ***
// On first load, show home view
showLoading("#main-content");
$ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(
  allCategoriesUrl,
  buildAndShowHomeHTML, // ***** <---- TODO: STEP 1: Substitute [...] ******
  true); // Explicitly setting the flag to get JSON from server processed into an object literal
});
// *** finish **


// Builds HTML for the home page based on categories array
// returned from the server.
function buildAndShowHomeHTML (categories) {

  // Load home snippet page
  $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(
    homeHtmlUrl,
    function (homeHtml) {

      // TODO: STEP 2: Here, call chooseRandomCategory, passing it retrieved 'categories'
      // Pay attention to what type of data that function returns vs what the chosenCategoryShortName
      // variable's name implies it expects.
      var chosenCategoryShortName = chooseRandomCategory(categories).short_name;


      // TODO: STEP 3: Substitute {{randomCategoryShortName}} in the home html snippet with the
      // chosen category from STEP 2. Use existing insertProperty function for that purpose.
      // Look through this code for an example of how to use the insertProperty function.
      // WARNING! You are inserting something that will have to result in a valid Javascript
      // syntax because the substitution of {{randomCategoryShortName}} becomes an argument
      // being passed into the $dc.loadMenuItems function. Think about what that argument needs
      // to look like. For example, a valid call would look something like this:
      // $dc.loadMenuItems('L')
      // Hint: you need to surround the chosen category short name with something before inserting
      // it into the home html snippet.
      //
      var homeHtmlToInsertIntoMainPage = insertProperty(homeHtml, "randomCategoryShortName", "\'" + chosenCategoryShortName + "\'");


      // TODO: STEP 4: Insert the produced HTML in STEP 3 into the main page
      // Use the existing insertHtml function for that purpose. Look through this code for an example
      // of how to do that.
      insertHtml("#main-content", homeHtmlToInsertIntoMainPage);

    },
    false); // False here because we are getting just regular HTML from the server, so no need to process JSON.
}
```

In Step 1 it's simple, just substitute .... with the function buildAndShowHomeHTML, but the value, so no parentheses, because it's just a handle for the function that sends the HTTP get request. I did that already so you see the result here.

In Step 2, we use the accessory function chooseRandomCategory written for us and pass it the categories object, and then do .short_name property because that's what we want for further processing.

In Step 3, I assign to var homeHtmlToInsertIntoMainPage using accessory function insertProperty, passing in the html we want to modify, the token "randomCategoryShortName" as where we want to substitute {{randomCategoryShortName}}, and, escaping quotes so that the evaluated variable is processed correctly: "'" + chosenCategoryShortName + "'". I don't remember why that is necessary but if my logic is right then it is.

Step 4 uses insertHtml at the tag #main-content ID and inserts the HTML in the main page.

That should be it!

But I load the page and get the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/web%20design/Coursera/HTML,%20CSS,%20&%20JavaScript/fullstack-course4/assignments/assignment5/assignment5-solution-starter/snippets/home-snippet.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.
> ajax-utils.js:34

```
GET file:///D:/web%20design/Coursera/HTML,%20CSS,%20&%20JavaScript/fullstack-course4/assignments/assignment5/assignment5-solution-starter/snippets/home-snippet.html net::ERR_FAILED
```

and here's the code for home-snippet.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <img src="images/jumbotron_768.jpg" alt="Picture of restaurant" class="img-responsive visible-xs">
    </div>

    <div id="home-tiles" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" onclick="$dc.loadMenuCategories();"><div id="menu-tile"><span>menu</span></div></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="#" onclick="$dc.loadMenuItems({{randomCategoryShortName}});">
          <div id="specials-tile"><span>specials</span></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/David+Chu's+China+Bistro/@39.3635874,-76.7138622,17z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x89c81a14e7817803:0xab20a0e99daa17ea!2sDavid+Chu's+China+Bistro!3m1!1s0x89c81a14e7817803:0xab20a0e99daa17ea" target="_blank">
          <div id="map-tile">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3084.675372390488!2d-76.71386218529199!3d39.3635874269356!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c81a14e7817803%3A0xab20a0e99daa17ea!2sDavid+Chu&#39;s+China+Bistro!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1452824864156" width="100%" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <span>map</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End of #home-tiles -->
```

this snippet isn't accessed anywhere in steps 1-4 so I have no idea what's going wrong. I really just have no clue what to do now.

Many thanks,

Anna

Comment: See the error - _"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted"_ You will need to load the page from a "proper" web server to be able to do Cross Origin requests. You appear to be opening the page from the file system.

Comment: ohh yes, you was right, thanks alot. I got it :)